# Help Identifying this Circuit board

Tags: identification

The question is straightforward! I have searched the internet on basically everything written on this board and I can not find it. Anyone who could help me with that, or help me with using it would be a great help!
PS:I can provide more info, if something isn't clear in any of the pictures or you have a question about what it looks like in an area just comment and ask, and I will clarify.
PSS: There is nothing(in terms of words) on the back of the board.

Edit: The board interfaces with a small camera (what the 2x16 input array is for). And is mounted on a rotating x and y platform with two servos (not connected to it). 
Also it is made to go with a [cRio]: http://www.ni.com/compactrio/

(Links for photos)

[image: http://www.truploader.com/uploads/1_9_2012/4673500109021957.jpg]

[image: http://www.truploader.com/uploads/1_9_2012/5464600109022000.jpg]

[image: http://www.truploader.com/uploads/1_9_2012/4410580109021959.jpg]

Comment: The board seems to be a part of a more complex device. Can you describe the device? Also +1 for actually posting images with readable component numbers.

Comment: Middle photo is excellent - larger would be better (ie move in to remove external stuff if it will focus) but it's very usable.  
 Other two apparently identical photos are not sharp - sharp is easy - lots of light, steady hand, further away if it won't focus, repeat till sharp. Sharp and smaller beats big and fuzzy. Not trunated half wat across the main IC also helps :-). Square on helps heaps too.

Comment: It's sitting on a HITEC HS-322HD servo. Is that related in any way?

Comment: The servo is not related to it.

Comment: Got a serial port TTY? This thing looks like a single board computer.

Answer (score 2):

Summarised_solution:

- SX52 is a fast micricontroller leanin towards I/O processing use.
- LM2940 is a voltage regulator.
- FR0627 is unknown but probably a large memory IC
- Tell us more and we'll tell you more.

UBICOM were Scenix. The SX52 can be thought of as a general purpose microcontroller and a fast clock and a bias towards being used for peripheral conrol tasks. But 'just another microcontroller" is not totally wrong.

The RS232 port suggests some sorts of communications controller. Possibly for a game. If you told us more about what you must know about it and eg showed us a wider outside picture of the box it would help muchly. Are we liable for the mentioned $1,000 fine if we help you? :-)

SX52BD is a "communications leaning" microcontroller IC - that's a pretty general title - see specs below. It is usually used for moving data in and out of a system and perhaps processing it as it goes. This could be in a game or a business communications system or ??? The outside of the box which you have not showed us or told us about probably makes its function much clearer.

DB9 connector is very likely a RS232 serial but may be other coms IO.

SIPEX Sp232 IC is probably an RS232 level shifter (you should be able to find that  wuth ease) reonforcing the RS232 thought.

The LM2940 is on so many websites that your not finding it is stunning. It's a voltage regulator.

There is a lot of easily findable information on the components on the internet. You may wish to change search engines

Searching on

```
                ubicom sx52bd
```

Produced eg

[This data sheet](http://www.xgamestation.com/products/xgs_me/downloads/SX4852BD.pdf) which says -

- The Ubicom SX48BD/SX52BD/SX52BD75/SX52BD100
  are members of the SX family of configurable communications controllers fabricated in an advanced CMOS process technology. The advanced process, combined with
  a RISC-based architecture, allows high-speed computation, flexible I/O control, and efficient data manipulation.
  Throughput is enhanced by operating the device at frequencies up to 75 MHz and by optimizing the instruction
  set to include mostly single-cycle instructions. In addition,
  the SX architecture is deterministic and totally reprogramable. The unique combination of these characteristics
  enables the device to implement hard real-time functions
  as software modules (Virtual Peripheral™) to replace traditional hardware functions

And this useful analysis][(http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/498/SX52BD_PQ.php) which says

- April, 2002  SX48BD/SX52BD
  Configurable Communications Controllers with EE/Flash Program Memory, In-System Programming Capability, and On-Chip Debug

  PRODUCT OVERVIEW
  Introduction
  On-chip functions include two 16-bit timers with 8-bit prescalers supporting different operating modes (PWM, simultaneous PWM/capture, and external event counter), a general-purpose 8-bit timer with prescaler, an analog comparator, a brown-out detector, a watchdog timer, a power-save mode with multi-source wakeup capability, an internal R/C oscillator, user-selectable clock modes, and high-current outputs. The SX48BD and SX52BD are functionally the same, except for the package type and pinout. The SX48BD has four fewer pins and has only four rather than eight I/O pins for Port A. ... then repeats the material above.